# Why does my substring check return false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_substring(substring,string):

    for count in range(len(string)):

        if (string[count:count + len(substring)]) == substring:

            return True

        else:

            return False

print(is_substring('dab', 'abracadabra'))
```

If I try to only print the value of the condition like this:

```
def is_substring(substring,string):

    for count in range(len(string)):

        print (string[count:count + len(substring)]) == substring)

print(is_substring('dab', 'abracadabra'))
```

I get this output:

> python substrings.py
>
> abr
>
> bra
>
> rac
>
> aca
>
> cad
>
> ada
>
> dab
>
> abr
>
> bra
>
> ra
>
> a
>
> None

It prints the dab word, which is equal to the substring, but when I try to use an if condition to make equal to substring it returns false. Why does that return false?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] and a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do. For one, this is Python, so the indentation matters...

Comment: When asking questions anywhere on the internet, (a) try to avoid "halp me" and "i am a beginner" and statements of woe and suffering. (b) be clear about what your problem is. Write useful and informative titles. (c) format your code - most Q&A sites offer formatting tools. (d) use the correct case for English, and run your writing through a spell-checker. Stack Overflow is not a chat-room - we ideally want to keep questions forever, to help other developers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @halfer not that chat rooms would look gladly at broken English either!

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I'm not sure - have you ever read a Facebook chatroom? What they do to language and syntax in there... it's horrific. `:=)`

Comment: @halfer I was talking about the chatrooms on Stack Exchange and the corresponding diasporas on Discord!

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because this logic error is made commonly in many languages. There might be a better duplicate to mark available (something in Python :) or with more votes) but it's a bit difficult to search for this.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: oh yes, agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Your else returns after the first comparison. It should be coded like this:

```
def is_substring(substring, string):

    for count in range(len(string)):

        if (string[count:count + len(substring)]) == substring:
            return True

    return False

print(is_substring('dab', 'abracadabra'))
```